# Kernel SVC keeps getting errors on parameters in RandomSearchCV

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, jupyter, data-science

*This post continues from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51018058/i-keep-getting-attributeerror-in-randomsearchcv/51018209?noredirect=1#comment89030469_51018209)

```
classifier = SVC()
parameters = {"kernel": ["rbf", "linear"],
              "gamma": scipy.stats.expon(scale=.1),
              "c": scipy.stats.expon(scale=100),
              "class_weight": ["balanced", None]}

randomcv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=classifier, param_distributions=parameters,
                              scoring='accuracy', cv=10, n_jobs=-1,
                              random_state=0)
randomcv.fit(x_tu, y_tu)
```

Hi, I'm not sure what's causing the problem with the code above.

I'm getting a really long error message from [here](https://pastebin.com/eE4XA5Vb), and can't read what the error is telling me.

The same problem occurred when I was using a different classifier, but was able to solve them by changing the parameter range.

For this one, nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says

> Invalid parameter 'c' for SVC()

This is because the actual parameter is `C` (capital C), see [SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html). Change the key `c` in the `parameters` to `C` and that should work